# why android:ellipsize="end" isn't working?

Tags: android

I don't know why `ellipsize="end"` doesn't work.
I expect the 3 dots to occur where the red circle is.
I've added the code of my XML and an image from the android studio preview of XML:

**Just in case** I have already tried to use:

```
singleLine=true 
maxLength=1 (although i dont want it - for the check) 
maxLines=x  (although i dont want it - for the check) 
layout_height=60dp  (for checking dixed size)
```

[image: preview on studio]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/startGuideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.08"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/endGuideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            tools:src="@drawable/broken_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cornersBG"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornersBG"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.41"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/corener_radius_rectangle_blackbalue900"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/startGuideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/endGuideline">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="ROOKIE"
                android:textAppearance="@style/MontserratFont.XXL.ExtraBold"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:text="מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מימילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מימילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מימילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מימילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מימילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מילים מיליםמילים מילימיליםמילים מילימיליםמילים מילימילים ם מילים ם "
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textAppearance="@style/AssistantFont.M"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/beginBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/begin"
                android:textAppearance="@style/AssistantFont.M.Bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Would you expect to have '...' on the end of your screenshot? Where you've drawn a red circle.

Comment: YES. this is what i excpect

Comment: That's not the behaviour of ellipsize... Ellipsize will add '...' to the end of your text IF your full text can't be shown on your screen. In your case, their is enough space to show all the text.

Comment: ive already mentioned that i limited the size to full.

Comment: So in your screenshot not all the text is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wrap_content instead of 0dp (Match constraint layout).

Like this:

```
android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: i acutally dont want it to be single line, and height is required to fill the remaining space. therefor - height="0dp" and weight="1"

BTW - it is encapsulated inside LinearLayout